# error while starting xampp on fedora17

Tags: 64-bit, xampp, fedora

I currently installed xampp on my fedora (64 bit) system. i edited out the following code to make it 64 bit compatible.

```
# XAMPP is currently 32 bit only
#case `uname -m` in
#    *_64)
#    if /opt/lampp/bin/php -v > /dev/null 2>&1
#        then
#            :
#    else
#        $de && echo "XAMPP gibt es zur Zeit nur als 32-Bit Applikation. Bitte verwende eine 32-Bit Ko$
#        $de || echo "XAMPP is currently only availably as 32 bit application. Please use a 32 bit com$
#        exit
#    fi
#    ;;
#esac
```

but i am getting the following error

```
[root@localhost ~]# /opt/lampp/lampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...

/opt/lampp/share/lampp/phpstatus: /opt/lampp/bin/php: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL ...
/opt/lampp/bin/apachectl: /opt/lampp/bin/httpd: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

XAMPP: Error 126! Couldn't start Apache!
XAMPP: Starting diagnose...
XAMPP: Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP: Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/

XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: /opt/lampp/bin/my_print_defaults: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL!

XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP: /opt/lampp/lampp: /opt/lampp/sbin/proftpd: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Error 126! Couln't start ProFTPD!

XAMPP for Linux started.
```

Comment: Can you see the similarities between this and your editing of the 64bit check?   I was driving a car when the warning light lit up, warning me the car was out of fuel. It would not work anymore. So I smashed the warning light and it still not not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would you think that disabling the 64 bit check would magically make it work? This has no chance of ever working.

Moreover, you should never use lampp on fedora or any other distro that provides the relevant packages (read: all of them). Get rid of it and simply install the apache, mysql and php packages from the fedora repos.

Comment: +1: 100% approve this, then also if you plan to install some administrative panel for managing your server from the web (ex. `webmin`, `plesk`, etc) customized system configuration of *AMPP not be compatible with these panels, and configuration not be easily exportable to other machines and should always have a support dedicated to *AMPP.